# How to add `On Delete Cascade` to Join Table using JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities.

This is a coupon purchase system. it's create 3 tables for each entity and another table by the name of `customer_coupons` which hold all customer purchases by foreign keys

following DDL in the DB of `customer_coupons`

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_coupons` (
  `customer_id` int NOT NULL,
  `coupons_id` int NOT NULL,
  KEY `FK3ra7y4e2fu00kui0lby4mj0w1` (`coupons_id`),
  KEY `FK2xh7flxxfqpn6prhw5n06l4nn` (`customer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK2xh7flxxfqpn6prhw5n06l4nn` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK3ra7y4e2fu00kui0lby4mj0w1` FOREIGN KEY (`coupons_id`) REFERENCES `coupon` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Company Class:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String password;

    @Singular
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "company")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List<Coupon> coupons;
```

Customer Class:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @Singular
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List<Coupon> coupons;
```

Coupon Class:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Coupon {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @ManyToOne()
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Company company;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Category category;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private int amount;
    private double price;
    private String image;
```

I would to create a cascade delete, which when you delete a company in the DB, it will delete the all it's coupons and it will delete all coupon purchases. (it's the same, when you delete a customer, which doesn't delete the coupon, but delete the purchases in the join table)

**So my question is,** how do I add to the foreign key `coupons_id` on the `customer_coupons`  table the on delete cascade option

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how do I add to the foreign key coupons_id on delete cascade option

Comment: You've already done that "ON DELETE CASCADE" Doesn't it work?

Comment: It's on the customer_id side (works when you delete a customer), i need it to work on the coupon side aswell

Comment: And why don't you add it?

Comment: Cause I don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

You can define the foreign key with the `@JoinTable` annotation for both sides with the `@ForeignKey` annotation. In that definition you can specify your `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.